# Renewing TLS Certificate on an ingress resource in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-aks

The SSL Certificate used in our ingress resource has expired.

The Certificate is used alongside a private key in our ingress.

The task is to renew the SSL Certificate and apply it to the ingress resource.

We use DigiCert as our Certificate Authority.

We have generated a CSR and used it to generate an SSL Certificate.

But there is confusion over where the private key is, and how to install the new SSL Certificate.

What I have tried

is to use the existing private key in the TLS secret, and the new SSL Certificate.

But it doesn't work.

2. I generated a new private key, and CSR, used the CSR to get another SSL Certificate, it didn't work.

This is my workflow

Use OpenSSL to generate a new private key and CSR

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout kula-work.key -out kula.work.csr`

Use the CSR to generate a Certificate from DigiCert

Use new SSL Certificate and Private key to create a new TLS Secret

Reference the new TLS Secret in the Ingress resource

This is the error I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error on your screenshot indicates that you're still using the expired certificate, as per the Expired on/Current Date information. If you've followed all the configuration steps correctly, the issue is not certificate-related. Try clearing browser cache and restarting it. Also, check the DNS settings. It could be a DNS propagation delay.